# Frontmatter in roman numerals with \cleardoublepage causes extra arabic number to appear

Tags: page-numbering, report, front-matter

***Edit***

I am writing my thesis using `\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}` and I want the frontmatter to be in roman numerals. I add `\cleardoublepage` because people said I have to. This creates an (almost) blank page. However, this page still has a header line and a arabic number 2. **How do I make this into a completely blank page?** My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[inner = 30mm, outer = 20mm,  top = 30mm, bottom = 20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{apacite}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linktoc=all, allcolors=red,}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);},},}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{layouts}
%\usepackage{showframe}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Redefine the plain page style so chapter pages match my footer preference
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the footer visible
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\end{titlepage}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter*{Abstract}\label{ch:Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract} 

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}\label{ch:Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements} 

\chapter*{List of abbreviations}\label{ch:list of abbrev}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of abbreviations} 

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

And these are the pages I want to be completely blank:
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want your second page (Abstract, page number i)  to be treated as an even page instead of an odd one, wouldn't this confuse the reader? I would typically expect an even number on the left and an odd number on the right. If you don't add an emtpy page it would be the other way around.

Comment: I want the title page to be the front of my report. The first page (abstract) should be printed on the backside of the title page and thus come on the left.  That is exactly how it is, but if I add `\pagenumbering{roman}`, then it becomes a right-hand-side page

Comment: This is exactly what I meant with my previous comment. If you use the `\pagenumbering{roman}` command, your abstract page will be numbered with `i`. If you put this page on the back of your titlepage, you have an odd page number on a left page where one would expect an even number.

Comment: Maybe you are satisfied with putting the `\pagenumbering{roman}` command before the `titlepage` environment. This way, your titlepages is page `i` (pagenumber is not shown)  and the abstract page is page number `ii` and therefor an even and left page. (The result will be somewhat similat to the numbering scheme without any `\pagenumbering` command.)

Comment: I did not realise that anyone would expect the first page to be on the right. I want to minimize blank pages, and therefore I want the first page (abstract, numbered i) to be on the left.  When the arabic numbering starts, it should have no blank pages in between and it should follow the same left-right style as the roman part. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is easily possible. Apart from that, you can find a related question here: [How to change the page number from even to odd while keeping the page as verso?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36011/134144)

Comment: The title page is the first page. It has page number one, but usually the page number isn't printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load `emptypage`.

I have slightly modified your preamble, mainly commenting out useless or not available packages (`pgf-pie`) and adding a setting for `headheight`.

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[
  inner = 30mm,
  outer = 20mm,
  top = 30mm,
  bottom = 20mm,
  headheight = 13.6pt,
]{geometry}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\graphicspath{ {./Figures/} }
%\usepackage{gensymb} % what for?
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{layouts} % what for?
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11,
    /pgfplots/ybar legend/.style={
        /pgfplots/legend image code/.code={%
            \draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
            (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);},},}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linktoc=all, allcolors=red,}

\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% Redefine the plain page style so chapter pages match my footer preference
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[LE]{\thepage}
    \fancyfoot[RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the header invisible
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% Line at the footer visible
    }

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{Alph} % or roman
\begin{titlepage}
something
\end{titlepage}

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{roman}

\chapter{Abstract}\label{ch:Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}

Something

\chapter*{Acknowledgements}\label{ch:Acknowledgements}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgements} 

Something

\chapter*{List of abbreviations}\label{ch:list of abbrev}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of abbreviations} 

Something

\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

If you want the title page to be “i” and the abstract to be “iii”, just change `Alph` into `roman` and remove the next `\pagenumbering{roman}` instruction.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I use the other packages for figures and stuff that are not shown. I thought they might conflict so I did not remove them for this example. Why did you include the `headhight`setting?

Comment: @Hans Because otherwise the headers get misplaced: there is a warning by `fancyhdr` if the height is insufficient.